# sqljdbc4.jar - cannot connect to MSSQL server instance - SSL error?

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc

I'm using this code to connect to an MSSQL 2012 instance from OpenJDK1.8 using sqljdbc4.jar on an Ubuntu box:

```java
public static DataSource getMsSqlPoolSource(String server, String database, String user, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + server + ";databaseName=" + database + ";sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;";
    System.out.println("Connection String for MSSQL is:: " + connectionString);
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.ConnectionFactory factory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(connectionString, user, password);
    PoolableConnectionFactory poolFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(factory, null);
    ObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<>(poolFactory);
    poolFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
    PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection> dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);
    return dataSource;
}
```

This was working for three years, until today.

If I now try to connect from the same Ubuntu box to the same MSSQL 2012 instance as the past three years, I get an exception:

```
2021-07-31 10:01:07.125 ERROR vsCallLogSyncOnVerinet - SQL ERROR:: 1jyg0yezlh46 - invalid database address: jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.1.244;databaseName=my_DB;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;
Security providers: [SUN version 1.8, SunRsaSign version 1.8, SunEC version 1.8, SunJSSE version 1.8, SunJCE version 1.8, SunJGSS version 1.8, SunSASL version 1.8, XMLDSig version 1.8, SunPCSC version 1.8]
SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509/PKIX key/trust factories, SSLv3/TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2/TLSv1.3)
SSLContext provider services:
[SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory$Legacy
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator$Legacy
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4]
, SunJSSE: Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, 1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1.3.14.3.2.29]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> sun.security.ssl.RSASignature
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$X509
  aliases: [PKIX]
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
  aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509]
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context
  aliases: [SSLv3]
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.1 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS11Context
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.2 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS12Context
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.3 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS13Context
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
  aliases: [SSL]
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext
, SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 -> sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore
]
java.ext.dirs: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
```

I recently added some certificates to the OpenJDK1.8 certificate store for two domains unrelated to the direct by-ip connection on my local Class B where I connect to the local MSSQL instance via my Class B LAN.

Why is the MSSQL JDBC driver causing an apparent exception involving certificates suddenly, and refusing to connect?

I do not want the JDBC driver to use any certificate I added, it must just proceed normally and ignore them?

I have another Ubuntu machine using the same JDK version and the same JDBC driver, and the same JAR containing my app, it has no user-added certificates of any kind in the OpenJDK1.8 certificate store, and it can connect to the same MSSQL server using the JDBC driver with the same connection string, no problem.

Why would adding an SSL certficate for an unrelated domain on the internet I connect to from my Java app, now apparently cause the MSSQL Java JDBC driver in that app to try to use a random SSL certificate from the OpenJDK1.8 cert store to connect to the local MSSQSL server on the local by-ip Class B network?

Certificates were added like this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -importcert -alias lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed -file lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.der

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -importcert -alias lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed2 -file isrg-root-x1-cross-signed.der

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -importcert -alias lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed3 -file lets-encrypt-r3.der
```

EDIT: Managed to establish that the SSH certificates added above are not the problem - if I remove them from the trust store, the problem persists with JDBC connections exactly as above. The SSH certs loaded therefore has no effect on the JDBC connectivity issue e. g. that the connection attempt is returned as invalid database address.

Comment: Are you certain you didn’t remove existing certificates by accident? Have you run updates on both machines recently?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply.

I literally just added .der certificate files for a domain. The one machine is a recent, fresh Ubuntu 20.21 install with OpenJDK1.8, the other is an Ubuntu 20.21 updated about 3 months ago and recent till then, with OpenJDK1.8.... the older installed machine is still working, the new one with the certs loaded yesterday is the one where the JDBC instance cannot connect.

Comment: Try to log SSL debugging (start your application with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`), see also [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html). Also, recent Java versions by default disabled some of the older TLS versions. Make sure the `jre/lib/security/java.security` config files of both are the same.

Comment: Thanks Mark tried that I just get tens of thousands of lines logged to the console that look normal (at least a few hundred of them.) That's the thing I'm making two SSL connections from the app to two servers and that works 100% in both instances - the older Ubuntu instance app and the newer Ubuntu instance app - it is literally JUST the MSSQL JDBC connection that fails on the newer Ubuntu instance one with what looks to be the JDBC driver trying to make an SSL connection with a certificate to the MSSQL server which is not supported on the MSSQL server end.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a basic application only to reproduce the issue, and if you can reproduce it, then enable that logging. It should pinpoint where the SSL handshake fails (assuming that is what fails).

Comment: Also, have you tried a more recent version of the SQL Server JDBC driver? The latest versions no longer use the sqljdbc4 name, which means you're using an older driver version.

Comment: Roll back to your previous system configuration.

Comment: I'll have to try that next but I'm very wary of that, it is a codebase inherited from another dev that has left the company and often the slightest adjustment in Maven to any version of libraries used causes the application to become impossible to compile as object signatures change and method calls are suddenly sending too many / too few params, behaviour changes of vital components, etc. But thank you anyway.

Comment: It appears anyway I'm looking at a total collapse of the application, the MSSQL connection is VITAL to its use, I'll then have to rewrite it anyway from scratch (there's about 6 man years of dev sunk into the current one, do not relish redoing it myself but if the MSSQL connectivity cannot be made to work there will be no other choice.) Thanks again, much obliged for the comments.

Comment: Back the whole system up NOW and then reinstall the java certificates package.

Comment: Thor what is the "java certificates package"? I just installed the OpenJDK1.8 package, and loaded three .der files by hand as detailed above. Thank you for your help & comments!

Comment: The old working java might still be present on the system. Have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved with the kind assistance of Mark Rotteveel and AlwaysLearning.

**It had nothing to do with the SSL certificates loaded by me into OpenJDK1.8 trust store.**

The problem was threefold.

First, in my Netbeans 11 project, in the "Dependencies" folder, I had a jar called

MSSQL-4.0.jar

which was apparently placed there manually by a previous dev on the project.

I removed this file - I did not know which driver was being used, as I had a maven artifact as detailed above, ALSO for the MSSQL JDBC driver.

Second, AlwaysLearning then kindly pointed out that my connection exception to MSSQL was referring to SQLLite (NOT MSSQL) and the exception of an invalid database address was being reported by the SQLLite driver, NOT the MSSQL driver.

The core issue was that for some reason when I tried to connect to MSSQL using the source code as above, the MSSQL JDBC driver was trying an SQLLite connection to MSSQL.

This was why I was constantly getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address:jdbc:sqlserver://172.17.12.14;databaseName=DB;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;
```

as of course the SQLLite connection protocol will never work on an MSSQL server...

Thirdly, the exception on the connection attempt to MSSQL then changed to refer to the fact that the MSSQL server was using a too-old TLS encryption for the connection, and my client was rejecting this on the JDBC side - see above. Mark Rotteveel then assisted with editing the file

```
/etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security
```

on my Ubuntu 20.11 LTS OpenJKD1.8 install to lower the security on TLS so that my OpenJDK1.8 instance would allow the TLS encryption level the quite old MSSQL instance I was trying to connect to, was requiring.

In /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security I changed the line

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

to

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

So in summation, after removing the spurious MSSQL-4.0.jar from my NetBeans project's "Dependencies" folder, I also commented out the Maven artifacts for SQLLite (as it is no longer used in my project, and is a legacy library). Once the SQLLite library was removed by Maven on the next compile, AND I edited the java.security file as detailed above, the produced .JAR was able to connect to the MSSQL server from my Ubuntu machine, AFTER I lowered the security requirments in /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security and restarted my application on the Ubuntu machine using the OpenJDK1.8 installation.

This was because the MSSQL JDBC driver was now using a "genuine" MSSQL protocol to try to connect from my Ubuntu machine to the MSSQL server, instead of trying to use SQLLite protocol to connect to the MSSQL server, -AND- the JDBC driver was being allowed to talk an "old enough" TLS version to the MSSQL server after the changes to java.security.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Stefan

Comment: We have the same tls problem with an sqlserver 2012. That release is EOL’ed.  The proper long term solution is upgrading to a supported version of SQL server.

Comment: Also, this is why you should not make assumptions about what the actual problem is, because often you are wrong (or you would have fixed it yourself) Just describe the symptoms objectively and answer additional questions.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thank you sir, I will keep that in mind, and my assumptions were definitely at fault here. Thanks for taking the time to help / comment! Kind regards.